# Testing Fortran IPC: Sending 4 MiB of data using TCP/IP is equally fast as sending 100 B

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fortran

I am currently testing different ways to efficiently pass data between two Fortran programs. I have tried writing to file, pipes and TCP/IP. The results of my testing can be seen below. Please note that the graph only shows times for 4*10^4 B since this is how high I went for the file and pipes. The 4*10^6 B test was done only for the TCP/IP program.

In order to test the execution time I used the `time` program found in most Linux distributions, i.e: `time ./program`. I then used the `real` value as my time.

[image: Graph, showing the time it took to send, process, and send back data.]

It is clearly shown that writing to file, and using pipes, is quite linear. There's some overhead, but it's pretty straight forward. However, the TCP/IP protocol seems unaffected - regardless of the amount of data.

What is actually happening is:

- B.f90 is started and calls server.c, that starts a server on localhost:55555
- A.f90 is started and calls client.c, that connects to the server
- A.f90 passes N integers (each 4 bytes) to B.f90 (via the client/server)
- B.f90 squares each integers and sends them back to A.f90

The code that does this can be seen below, in 4 different programs. It is baffling to me that the TCP/IP version of the program seems unaffected by the amount of data. I tried sending 10^6 integers (4 MiB) right before posting this and it is as quick. 10^7 integers will however cause the program to crash (seg fault).

A.f90

```
program performance_test
use iso_c_binding, only: C_CHAR, C_NULL_CHAR, C_INT, C_PTR, C_LOC
implicit none

    ! Interfaces that ensure type compatability between Fortran and C.
    interface
        subroutine client(ipaddr, portnum) bind(C, name="client")
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_char, c_int
            character(kind=c_char) :: ipaddr(*)
            integer(kind=c_int), value :: portnum
        end subroutine client

        subroutine calc(indata, length) bind(C, name="calc")
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_ptr, c_int
            implicit none
            integer(c_int), value :: length
            type(c_ptr), value :: indata
        end subroutine calc

    end interface

    ! type declaration statements
    integer(c_int), allocatable, target :: array(:)
    type(c_ptr) :: cptr
    integer portno, length, i

    ! executable statements
    ! Call client.c and connect to localhost on port number `portno'.
    portno=55555
    call client(C_CHAR_"localhost"//C_NULL_CHAR, portno)

    ! Put numbers in the array
    length = 1000000
    allocate(array(0:length))
    cptr=c_loc(array(1))

    do i=1, length
        array(i) = 2
    end do

    ! Call client.c and pass the query on towards calcs.f90.
    call calc(cptr, length)

    deallocate(array)

end program performance_test
```

client.c

```
/* The original code for this client can be found here:
 * http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/client.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

// Static variables
static int sockfd;


/* This function is called when a system call fails. It displays a message about
 * the error on stderr and then aborts the program. */
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

/* Callable function from Fortran, used by calcf.f90, to connect to a server.
 */
int client(char *ipaddr, int in_portno)
{
    int portno;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    portno = in_portno;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(ipaddr);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    memset(((char *) &serv_addr), 0, (sizeof(serv_addr)));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(((char *)server->h_addr),
           ((char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr),
           (server->h_length));
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    return 0;
}

/* Callable function from Fortran, used by calcf.f90, as a calculator.
 * calc passes the query stored in buffer to server and returns the
 * answer. */
int *calc(int *indata, int length)
{

    int n;
    n = write(sockfd, indata, sizeof(int)*length);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");

    n = read(sockfd, indata, sizeof(int)*length);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");

    return indata;
}
```

server.c

```
/* The original code for this server can be found here:
 * http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/server.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

/* This function is called when a system call fails. It displays a message about
 * the error on stderr and then aborts the program. */
void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

/* Callable function from Fortran, used by calcs.f90, to start a server that
 * can recieve queries. */
int server(int in_portno)
{
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr; int n;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
       error("ERROR opening socket");

    memset(((char *) &serv_addr), 0, (sizeof(serv_addr)));

    portno = in_portno;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
             sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
             error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd,5);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1)
    {
        int length = 1000000;
        int indata[length];
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
             error("ERROR on accept");

        // Here comes the query from client.c
        n = read(newsockfd, indata, sizeof(int)*length);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

        square(indata);

        // write returns the data to the client
        n = write(newsockfd, indata, sizeof(int)*length);

        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

B.f90

```
program calculator_server

! Calculator at the server side of the client/server calculator
! Responsible for starting up the server server.c

use iso_c_binding, only: C_CHAR, C_NULL_CHAR, C_INT, C_PTR
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    integer calc, ans, portnum, calculate

    ! Interface that ensures type compatibility between Fortran and C
    interface
        subroutine server(portnum) bind(C, name="server")
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_int
            integer(kind=c_int), value :: portnum
        end subroutine server
        subroutine square(intarray) bind(C, name="square")
            use iso_c_binding
            type(c_ptr), value :: intarray
        end subroutine square
    end interface

    ! Start the server with portnumber
    portnum = 55555
    call server(portnum)

end program calculator_server


! **********************************************************************
subroutine square(cptr) bind(C, name="square")
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    ! Variable declarations
    type(c_ptr) :: cptr
    integer*8 :: iptr
    integer :: length, i
    integer pointee(1000000)
    pointer(iptr, pointee)
    iptr = loc(cptr)
    length = 1000000

    ! Execution
    do i = 1, length
        pointee(i)= pointee(i)**2
    end do
end subroutine square
```

My question is simply if I am missing something. Naturally, I have printed the data at various stages of the program to ensure it is actually passed, and squared, and sent back, so the program does what it is supposed to do. However, I cannot comprehend that the amount of data does not matter. I am currently unable to try the program on two different machines, or I would have done that too.

Any ideas about what could be causing this behavior is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of integers (say, to ten or maybe even a hundred million) you send? How do you measure the times?

Comment: This is just what the graph shows. I started by sending 25 integers (25*4 = 100 B of data), then increased it in accordance with the graph. When I reached 10*10^6 integers (i.e. 40*10^6 = 40 MiB of data) I got a seg fault and I never dug into why. I will most likely never send more than 10^4 B of data at the time anyway, but I wanted to see what happened.

The times are measured using the `time`command in your arbitrary Linux distribution. This specific one being OpenSuse 13.1 (Bottle).

Comment: From what I see the graph you provide shows the performance when you send messages of up to `4*10^4 bytes`.  Before we all break out our test boxes and crystal balls, reassure us that you haven't made a fundamental error.  Tell us also how you timed the operations.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I edited my post for clarity. The 4*10^6 B test was run only with the TCP/IP program, why it is not present in the graph. However, as can be seen in the graph, the question is as interesting for the 4*10^4 B run.

Comment: What, physically, is this Ethernet of which you speak? If it is 10GE the (admittedly minimum) time it can take for your longest message is 4000000/10000000000=0.4ms, so all you would see is the overhead in your program. I'd try sending the message many times and averaging. No, actually I would use MPI, but that's not what you were asking.

Comment: @IanBush, I am not leaving the computer, as can be seen in the code I am passing the data via localhost. I have started to look into MPI as well, but don't really see it working in the way I want to use the programs.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem: `read()` may return less data then requested. Likewise, `send()` might not send all the data. Inserting a couple of `printf()` in the following way to *server.c*

```
// Here comes the query from client.c
n = read(newsockfd, indata, sizeof(int)*length);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

printf("received %d, expected %lu\n", n, sizeof(int)*length);
square(indata);

// write returns the data to the client
n = write(newsockfd, indata, sizeof(int)*length);
printf("sent %d out of %lu\n", n, sizeof(int)*length);
```

printed out when executing

> received 43690, expected 4000000
>
> sent 2539008 out of 4000000

So only 1/90 of expected data was received.